# Passing a variable between multiple frames

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I have a system in which  currently I have 4 interfaces named as Meals, appetizers, Beverages, fast-food.

Each interface having its own category of goods , once selected by customer I want to insert those to DB and retrieve for showing the order details in Order panel and when proceeded to pay i want to calculate a bill for each customer having a unique order id for each customer.

The Question for me is how to calculate the bill at the end?

From my understanding if I created a variable in meals and can assign the same to other interfaces as well and only when the customer select payment the variable is increased in the system by one , so there will be no errors of calculating bill. I cant seem to find a way through to implement that ..

For example: I fairly new to this i simply ask forgive if theres is uncertainty caused from the way which i asked the question...
--Java

```
 //Start up menu
        public class  Meal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    }
    //Second menu 
    public class Fastfoods extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    }
    //Third Menu
    public class Beverages extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    }
    //fourth menu
    public class Appetizers extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    }
```

Comment: I think my understanding of your terminology is different to yours. For example, when you write _insert those to DB_, are you talking about a database such as [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) ? If yes, then I assume that the database contains all the details, including prices, so why not just execute a SQL query to return the cost of the meal?

Comment: As you refer to get details to the order panel by a query to the database it would mean that i will be not inserting any details in to a table in sqldatabase , but just reterive once thats already avaiable , but how may i make it possible for all my popup (popups are avaible for each meal)  for selection of order which iis another java frame , i think it would be ineffecient , or i dont understand how to implement it , Can you please help me understand , thanks

Comment: When building a complex Swing GUI, the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern helps to separate concerns.  First, create an application model that holds a List of food items.  The application model is made up of one or more plain Java classes.  Next, create a view with one JFrame and multiple JPanels to display the information from the model and accept new information.  Your JButton ActionListeners make up the controller classes that update the model and refresh  the view.